# PHP / MySQL delete DUPLICATE rows and PREVENT duplicates in the future

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I know this has been asked before, but I'm not a coder, and cannot figure it out from other similar posts. I've spent over 5 hours trying to figure this out with great unsuccess :( So I ask for your help.

**1) Prevent Duplicates**

I have a PHP script that writes to DB. Here is the code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO results (total, size, persq, strip, material, region) 
VALUES ('$total', '$size', '$persq', '$strip', '$material', '$region')";
```

I want to prevent duplicate rows based on TOTAL and SIZE columns. So if a new entry matches value in TOTAL and SIZE, do not enter new row.

**2) Delete Duplicates**

I want to delete ALL existing douplicate rows from DB, also based on TOTAL and SIZE columns.

If row contains duplicates in both TOTAL and SIZE, delete entire row.

How do I do this?

**PS** - I've read that I can use SQL IGNORE command to prevent futue duplicates - example (i've tryed to structure it to work for my situation:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO results ...;
```

would something like this work? If so please help me structure it (i'm new to PHP and MySQL).

Big thanks in advance.

Comment: Apply Unique key to (total,size) will prevent future duplicates.

Comment: I think `INSERT IGNORE` will only check if the primary key already exists. I don't know if it checks every unique constraint. But you can just try to insert the record and check whether it works. Anyway, Bhavik's advice of adding a unique key is the right starting point (after removing the duplicates, that is)

Comment: @GolezTrol If I start from scratch (drop existing table) and set TOTAL and SIZE to be `int NOT NULL UNIQUE` and use use `INSERT IGNORE` will that avoid douplicates? If so, I can just strt from scratch (data in DB is not essential, as it will repopulate fast anyway)

Comment: I think Size and Total should not each be unique but only the combination of them.

Comment: @GozelTrol - after some testing, I figured that I do only need TOTAL to be unique. Also, I ended up dropping th whole table, and recreating it, making total UNIQUE VARCHAR (not INT). I dropped table becuase GROUPING realle messed up how results display (logically) ... anyway - thank you for your help. Now my DB is easier to use and more accurate and is not populated with duplicates  ... although all data is gone :D

Comment: @bhivak that's exactly what I did ... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to remove the duplicates is to use a CTAS (Create Table As Select) statement to create a temporary table for your data. Using `group by`, you can remove the duplicates. MySQL is 'smart' enough to just pick any value for the other fields from one of the rows that match the group.

```
/* De-duplicate and copy all the data to a temporary table. */
CREATE TABLE Temp AS
  SELECT * FROM results
  GROUP BY total, size;

/* Delete all data from your current table. Truncate is faster but more dangerous. */
DELETE FROM results; /* TRUNCATE results; */

/* Insert the de-duplicated data back into your table. */
INSERT INTO results
SELECT * FROM Temp;

/* Drop the temporary table. */
DROP TABLE Temp;
```

After that you can add a unique constraint for `total,size` to prevent new duplicates.

```
ALTER TABLE results 
  ADD UNIQUE results_uni_total_size (total, size);
```

Comment: how do I add **unique constraint** for Total, Size?

Comment: I just added that for completeness, although I think a developer should be able to find such information once given concrete terms like ['add', 'unique' and 'constraint'](https://www.google.nl/webhp?#safe=off&q=mysql+add+unique+constraint). ;)

Comment: thanks for your time - I really appreciate it. I'm not a developer - I'm a roofer with CS background. It's just EASIER (not cheaper) to figure this out myself than to hire a developer.

Comment: Kudos for trying yourself. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have duplicate rows where EVERY column has a duplicate value, the easiest thing to do is crate a new table and import all of the rows using a group by on every column.  First create a new table with each column set as a unique key:

```
CREATE TABLE newresults total INT NOT NULL, size ...
UNIQUE KEY (total, size, presq, strip, material, region)
```

Then push clean values into the new table:

```
INSERT INTO newresults (total, size, persq, strip, material, region) SELECT total, size, persq, strip, material, region FROM RESULTS GROUP BY total, size, persq, strip, material, region
```

That will give you a clean data set.  The final thing you'll have to do is drop the old table and rename newresults to results:

```
DROP TABLE results;
RENAME TABLE mydatabase.newresults TO mydatabase.results
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: That is the easiest solution if you don't have any foreign key constraints indexes or other things related to the original table.

Comment: @Michael Bissell - I did not need every field to be unique. Originally I wanted TOTAL and SIZE to be UNIQUE, but ended up making only total column unique. Thanks for your input

Comment: By grouping them this becomes a key -- UNIQUE (col1, col2) means that you can have values "1, 2" as one key and "1, 3" as another -- col 1 can have duplicate values and col 2 can have duplicate values, but you can't have two rows with the same values in col1 and col2.